# Oracle procedure ref cursor

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, cursor

I have this Oracle procedure:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE TEST  

(
p_ResultSet        OUT  INFMTTO_CURSOR.cursorType
)

AS

BEGIN
  OPEN p_ResultSet FOR
  SELECT *
  FROM V_INFOMTTO_P1_SITES;
END TEST;
```

A package where the cursor is declared:

```
create or replace PACKAGE INFMTTO_CURSOR AS 
  type cursorType is ref cursor;  
END INFMTTO_CURSOR;
```

If I call the procedure in SQL developer with this line:

```
exec TEST
```

the result is empty. ¿Can you help me please?, how can I obtein the table result through the EXEC function?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You don't have to define the explicitly, there is a pre-defined type, simply use `p_ResultSet OUT SYS_REFCURSOR`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need define a `refcursor` to recieve your data. Try this:

```
var r refcursor;
execute TEST( :r );
print :r;
```

Good luck!